# Find an infinite domain so quantified statement can be true

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$(\forall x \in D)(\forall y\in D)(\exists z \in D)[z=x+y]\land(\exists x\in D)(\exists y\in D)(\forall z \in D)[z\neq xy]$
find an infinite domain D so that the statement is false/true

I got that as long as $x/(x-1)= y$ can happen, the statement is false
so as long as $x\neq1$ the statement is false..
I am still very confused..
Is there so such domain that would make the statement true?

Answer (score 2):

The set

$D = \{ k\sqrt{2} \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is closed under addition but not under multiplication.